# Weird behaviour of form and widget in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have following simple form field

```
class PhoneField(CharField):
    widget = PhoneWidget


    def clean(self, value):
        value = re.sub('\D', '', super(PhoneField, self).clean(value))
        if len(value) < 7:
            raise ValidationError(_("Phone number is too short"), code='too_short')
        return value
```

However, widget is still text input.
However, if I write

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['widget'] = PhoneWidget
    super(PhoneField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then it works perfectly. Digging in the code I noticed, that if widget is not specified in kwargs, then self.widget is used, but it is not a case. Why is that?

Note, that I don't pass widget in code.

```
field = PhoneField(label='Phone')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
The problem was in admin. Admin passed in `kwargs` default widget for CharField - `widgets.AdminTextInputWidget`.